# Rake aborted undefined method `each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

good afternoon.
Can`t deal with cancer db: migrate

user@ubuntu:~/furriery/furriery$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
undefined method `each' for "../.openshift/config/database.yml":String
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in`resolve_all'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in`configurations='
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`instance_eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in`block in on_load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in`on_load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in`initialize!'
/home/user/furriery/furriery/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in`require_environment!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [i686-linux]
Rails 4.1.4
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

Answer (score 1):

Check your database.yml file and make sure each ":" separator is followed by a space.  Also make sure that you have spaces, not tabs, for indentation.  You can check your file to see if it's valid YAML here: http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: The site http://www.yamllint.com/ checking file .yml
Swears on line <<: * <% = ENV ['RAILS_DB'] || "sqlite"%>
(<unknown>): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an alias at line 27, column 7